# Posting multiple arrays with $http service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)and have two arrays that I would like to post to a [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) server to be processed and sent in a confirmation email. Any thoughts on the how to properly submit these arrays?

**Here are the two arrays:**

```
var array1 = vm.contacts;
var array2 = vm.projects;
```

**$http service:**

```
data = array1; // Is it possible to add array2 here too?

$http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/emails', data)
  .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);

    }, function(response) {
      console.log('error', response);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you not creating an array of these two arrays and sending it ?

Comment: @Luke P. Issac I'm grabbing two separate arrays from a Firebase database. I'm not really sure how to create an array of these two arrays. I suppose that's part of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send an object that contains those arrays. Something like this:

```
var vm = {};
vm.contacts = []; // Array of contacts.
vm.projects = []; // Array of projects.
var data = vm; // Object with arrays.
```

**In your $http service:**

```
$http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/emails', data)
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data); // Use response.data to show your response.
}, function (response) {
    console.log('error', response);
}
```

**Updated:**

By this way you might to send arrays of arrays. Something like this:

```
var vm = {};
vm.contacts = [];
vm.projects = [];

var arrays = [];
var array1 = vm.contacts;
var array2 = vm.projects;

arrays.push(array1, array2);
console.log(arrays);
var data = arrays;
```

Then:

**In your $http service:**

```
$http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/emails', data)
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data); // Use response.data to show your response.
}, function (response) {
    console.log('error', response);
}
```